# installing usbmuxd under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, libusb

I installed the latest version of [libusb](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/latest/download) and now I'm trying to install [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd).

However, it gives this error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libusb-1.0 >= 1.0.3) were not met:

No package 'libusb-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

In the installation log of libusb it says

```
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libusb-1.0.0.dylib /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib
```

It looks like the wrong version of the library is getting installed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider installing [macports](http://macports.org), which has usbmuxd v1.0.7 [available](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=usbmuxd), and then:

```
$ sudo port selfupdate
$ sudo port install usbmuxd
```

(you should de-install the `libusb` package you installed yourself, before doing this probably).